# What is the difference between cts:search and cts:element-attribute-values?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, cts-search

I can't understand deference between `cts:search` and `cts:element-attribute-values`.
I can get the same result with both these functions.
What is the best resolve?

```
cts:search(/t:ancestors-list/t:concept/t:concept-ancestor, cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("t:concept-ancestor"), $concept/id))/@subject
```

or

```
cts:element-attribute-values(
  xs:QName("t:concept-ancestor"),
  xs:QName("subject"),
  (),
  ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"),
  cts:element-value-query(
    xs:QName("t:concept-ancestor"),
    $concept/id
  )
)
```

**ar:concept-ancestor** is the element range index and element attribute range index.

And **xml** structure like this

```
<t:ancestors-list xmlns:ar="http://test.com">
    <t:concept subject="http://test.com/concept#1c5cd7082ac908c62e9176770ae0fb53">
        <t:concept-ancestor subject="http://test.com/concept#1c5cd7082ac908c62e9176770ae0fb53">4a1f650290103d39863bf7bc22ef18aa</t:concept-ancestor>
    </t:concept>
    <t:concept subject="http://test.com/concept#05b707457f79f42c93bf778915e4a589">
        <t:concept-ancestor subject="http://test.com/concept#05b707457f79f42c93bf778915e4a589">4a1f650290103d39863bf7bc22ef18aa</t:concept-ancestor>
        <t:concept-ancestor subject="http://test.com/concept#05b707457f79f42c93bf778915e4a589">1c5cd7082ac908c62e9176770ae0fb53</t:concept-ancestor>
    </t:concept>
    ...
</t:ancestors-list>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`cts:element-attribute-values` requires an element-attribute range index be configured on the values you're querying, and it only returns an atomic type (`xs:anyAtomicType*`). `cts:search` returns document nodes, and no indexes are required for `cts:element-value-query`.

If you only need the values (not XML) and you already have an index, then the `cts:element-attribute-values` query will be faster.

Comment: Facets are an example of where you might want one of the cts:*-values functions -- a list of values from an index that helps your user browse.

Comment: I may be wrong, but to my understanding `cts:element-value-query` will be more accurate and faster if there is an index though. Apart from this, not retrieving nodes from the database, but using index values instead is much more performant, and scales much better..

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! I can't understand why first example works faster. And I have to say that second returns time out error. I thought that indexes has to work faster and more stable

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental difference is that `cts:search` returns a sequence of nodes within which the `cts:element-value-query` is satisfied, while the `cts:element-attribute-values`function returns a stream of the actual attribute values that are defined in your index (where the values are further limited by the `cts:element-value-query` that you pass to the function).

I can think of several possible reasons for the difference in speed, but this seems to me to be the key:

The `cts:search` operation has to load and return to you a **sequence** of `concept:ancestor` nodes that satisfy the search criteria.  The `cts:element-attribute-values` function call returns a **stream** of **values**.

Loading and sending a **sequence** of **nodes** is going to be more time- and memory-expensive than giving you a **stream** of **atomic values**. A sequence (whether it's of nodes() or atomic values) will get fully loaded into memory before it is returned to you, while a stream of atomic values is lazy-loading, so that it doesn't (necessarily) store all the values in memory at once.

(I just learned about the sequence/stream distinction, and the `cts:element-values` and `cts:element-attribute-values`functions from a just-added post on the MarkLogic Community Blog: [Result Streams from Range Indexes](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/xquery-result-streams).)

The bottom line, though, in choosing between the two approaches has already been suggested by wst:

> If you only need the values (not XML) and you already have an index, then the `cts:element-attribute-values` query will be faster.